# Can You Help me Understand This M.2 SATA NVMe PCIe SSD Gen 3/4 x34 x64 4x4 Nonsense?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, storage, nvme, m.2

So right off the bat I'll say that I'm a Software Engineer and I've been building computers for decades (up until 5-6 years ago) so I am technology literate, however trying to understand these new storage technologies is driving me up a wall. I think the major issue is that every article I read explains one thing and then turns right around and contradicts itself in the very next sentence. For example:

"M.2 is the SSD form factor whereas NVMe is a data transfer protocol." 
(very next line) 
"NVMe drives use the M.2 form factor."
(very next line)
"Make sure your M.2 drive is utilizing the NVMe interface protocol."

So what the hell is NVMe, a protocol or a physical type of drive? A protocol or an interface to plug the drive into?

Then you go on YouTube and see NVMe vs SSD vs M.2 vs HDD. Well if M.2 is just an SSD form factor, and NVMe is just a transfer protocol, then what the hell are they comparing? Should they be saying M.2 SSD using SATA vs M.2 SSD using NVMe vs 2.5 inch SSD using SATA vs HDD?

Then I go online and see an article "Which is faster NVMe or PCIe?" Well if NVMe is the fastest [protocol] then why are they comparing it to an interface?

You see where I'm going with this. I know for a fact that these terms are not interchangeable, so I have no idea why no one seems to be capable of explaining this clearly. I could if I could understand it first. I haven't even gotten into the 2x4 4x4 Gen 3/4 crap yet.

I just want to find an AM4 motherboard that supports two of the fastest storage devices out there on the board. Most of the boards I've seen only have x1 Gen 4 and x1 gen 3. Which makes no sense, but whatever. I can't even figure out which slots to look for and what drives to stick in there. Last time I built a computer there were two options... SATA HDD or SATA SSD. SATA SSD was cutting edge.

If anyone out there understands this stuff (extremely well) could you please help me make sense of it.

Comment: `NVMe drives use the M.2 form factor.` doesn't contradict the surrounding statements

Comment: Read them again. Slowly

Comment: interpreting the second statement: *Drives using the NVMe data transfer protocol are physically in the M.2 form factor.* - interpreting the third statement: *M.2 form factor drives can either be SSD or NVMe, so, if you want an M.2 NVMe driver make sure it is an NVMe drive, not an SSD drive (I have 4 x M.2 NVMe and 1 x M.2 SSD)* there is no contradiction

Comment: as far as available PCIe slots on the motherboard (x1, x4 etc Gen3/Gen4) that is irrelevant, since 99% of AM4 motherboards come with 1, 2 or even more M.2 slots, which will be PCIe X4 Gen 3/4 (depending on the capabilities of the motherboard) - I have four AM4 boards with an M.2 Gen3 x4,  and one with M.2 Gen4 x4 - all my NVMe drives are Gen4 x4 and all work anywhere, due to the backwards compatibility of PCIe generations. In short, you're overthinking the issue :p

Comment: I do understand the Gen 3/4 compatibility, but I don't understand why the boards only come with x1 Gen 4 and x1 Gen 3. Gen 4 is twice as fast, so why wouldn't they give us two Gen 4? I have yet to find one with two of them. And I agree with you that I'm likely overthinking this, but I can't help it. I just can't make sense of it.

Comment: `so why wouldn't they give us two Gen 4` some of my boards with Gen3 M.2 also have a second Gen2 x2 M.2!! it may have to do with cost, it may have to do with chipset vs cpu PCIe lanes etc. my X570 based board has two Gen4 x4 - so, perhaps look at X570 boards (my other boards are X470, X370 and a320 FYI)

Comment: I'm taking your advice and going for the X570 based board. Also, I figured out why all boards only have the one Gen 4 slot. Ryzen only supports x number of PCIe lanes, which are divided up among all the interconnects, so there simply isn't enough for each slot to have 4 lanes.

Comment: I think B550 will also have Gen4 M.2 - of course motherboard manufacturers can do what they want! I would read the specifications, just make sure at least one M.2 Type M slot is Gen4 and you should be good (as long as the CPU is new enough of course, i.e. Ryzen 3000 series or later, having said that, the 2000 series will still work with a Gen4 M.2 device, just at Gen3 speed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: NVMe is faster. NVMe is PCIe used for storage.PCIe is always faster than SATA

I think the easiest way to understand this is to break it up into *electrical/data* standards and *physical* form factors.

Your 'traditional' 2.5 and 3.5 inch hard disk drives use physical and electrical sata standards for connectors

[image]
<sub>By Dsimic at English Wikipedia, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=31262121</sub>

M.2 is a *different* family of connectors physically

[image]

<sub>By Sayeen - Own work, CC BY-SA 4.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=130292724</sub>

You'd notice the top and bottom pairs of connectors are keyed differently.

The top two are SATA M.2 and the bottom 2 are PCIe M.2

NVMe is the storage protocol that PCIe M.2 drives use - so all M.2 NVMe drives *are* PCIe. There's a few 'full sized' PCIe SSD around as well, but that's generally outside the scope of most folks who arn't running a rack at home for fun

*Generally* as of 2023, most M.2 drives are 2280. There's exceptions but you don't need to worry about them (the last 2 numbers indicate length in mm). Most PCs unless the manual says otherwise will accept either.

> x1 Gen 4 and x1 gen 3

Its backward compatible. Gen 4 is faster than Gen 3 - its *exactly* the same as with different 'full sized' PCIe generations. I *think* Gen 5 uses a different physical connector. Basically the bigger number the better.

Practically if you want the fastest drive, match the generation of your slot with the drive (so if you have a PCIe gen 4, *get* a gen 4 compatible SSD, and if you have gen 3, get a gen 3 or 4 drive), *and* compare the ratings of the options you have - since  implementations, things like controllers and actual chips differ.

Most *desktop* PCs will support Sata *or* NVMe/PCIe drives UNLESS stated explicitly otherwise

Comment: `x1 Gen 4` I've never seen an `x1` M.2 slot, most are x4, I do have a couple of boards with x2, but, never seen x1 `I think Gen 5 uses a different physical connector` if you're referring to Gen5 M.2, no, you can use Gen5 M.2 NVMe in a Gen4 or even Gen3 M.2 slot

Comment: I think this would be so much easier if the damn motherboard description simply said which type of storage to get. They list everything else. Supports Ryzen Gen 3 and newer. Supports DDR4 upto 4000mhz. Supports M.2 NVMe 2280 Gen 4.0. Would that be so hard?

Comment: you can put any M.2 NVMe drive into any M.2 slot (that takes storage, there are M.2 slots for other types of devices) ... so, `Supports M.2 NVMe 4.0` is not accurate as to what drive to get, you CAN use 3.0, 4.0 even 5.0 in a M.2 Gen4 slot

Comment: But you CAN'T put any M.2 drive into any M.2 slot. That's my point. Descriptions don't say whether they're SATA, NVMe, or PCIe. Or what width or length. Which is apparently a thing according to Journeyman.

Comment: you CAN put ANY M.2 drive into ANY (storage) M.2 slot - simple as that - the storage devices are either SATA or NVMe - there is no "PCIe M.2 drive"

Comment: yes, I have a system that had an M.2 SSD, and I swapped it with an M.2 NVMe Gen4 - despite the fact that the M.2 slot itself was Gen3

Comment: See now you just confused me again. M.2 SSD vs M.2 NVMe.  The way you phrased that makes it sound like you swapped out an SSD for and HDD. Like they're two completely different mediums. But then you make it sound like NVMe is a type of SSD. But then we already established that NVMe is nothing more than a transfer protocol similar to SATA.

See, I'm not crazy. It's just the way everyone tries to explain this stuff.

Comment: no - both devices were M.2 form factor, one using SATA protocol, the other using NVMe - my SATA M.2 states it is a M.2 SSD - sorry for the confusion, since NVMe are also SSD, since all SSD stands for is Solid State Drive ... I should've been more careful

Comment: Okay, so looking over Journeyman's post slowly a few times, and reviewing some motherboard manuals online, I think I understand it enough to purchase the board. I'm glad he pointed out the different sizes, because the board I was looking at specifically says 22110 won't fit. And if I understood him correctly, NVMe and PCIe are interchangeable concepts when dealing with M.2 storage, so that's what less thing to be confused about. Thank you both for you help.

Comment: @JoshCampbell Most 'full' PCs ought to support either PCIe/NVMe (they're the same) or SATA M.2 UNLESS it literally explicitly says its a Sata only slot. The only sata only slot I have come across was on what's essentially supposed to be a thin client -

Comment: You posted that 2 seconds after me. Explaining that the NVMe and PCIe are the same thing was a huge help.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - you don't need to worry - ALL `M.2 NVMe` (and `M.2 SATA`) storage devices will work in ALL M.2 slots<sup>*</sup>, however, not necessarily at full speed

Ignoring M.2 SATA storage, which uses SATA 3.0 (therefore limited to 6Gb/s), the following is what you need to know to determine at what "PCIe generation" the storage "connects"

- What PCIe Gen the CPU supports
- what PCIe Gen the Motherboard/Chipset supports
- What PCIe Gen the M.2 slot supports (you can have different slots on the same motherboard that support different Gen)
- What Gen is the M.2 NVMe device

The actual "PCIe Gen" used for connection is the lowest number from the above 4 - and that's it

Note: a majority of Storage M.2 slots are x4 slots, but, I have motherboards with a second M.2 slot being Gen2 x2 slot - that will also ultimately affect maximum throughput of the device to 10Gbs in this case

<sup>* as long as they are M.2 storage slots, you can have other M.2 types - i.e.wifi/networking for example - but motherboard specifications should specify if the slot is Storage or not</sup>

Answer (score 1):

NVMe is a bus protocol for accessing storage devices.  It supports multiple form factors, including PCI add in cards, U.2 and U.3 disk slots, and M.2.
(Note that U.3 also supports SATA and SAS, just for extra confusion.)

M.2 is a form factor that typically mounts directly on the motherboard and supports multiple lengths and widths of cards.  Note that M.2 supports multiple bus protocols including NVMe, AHCI, SATA, and is not limited to storage devices, but also supports other things like wifi.

There are multiple possible M.2 connectors with slightly different keying that supports different generations of devices.  So "NVME M.2" is not enough to know if a given device matches your motherboard.

Comment: In other words, you just explained to me why I'm so confused.

Comment: Yup, afraid so!